# KnockoutJS: How pass observable to custom binding?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

Javscript:

```
  var asdasd = {
    test: ko.observableArray([0, 50])
  };

  alert(asdasd.test()); //0,50

  asdasd.test.subscribe(function() {
    return alert("I was changed!!");
  });

  ko.bindingHandlers.rangeslider = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
      var length;

      length = valueAccessor().length; //0 =(
      return alert("Why valueAccessor().length is " + length + " when it wasn't changed? =((");
    }
  };

  ko.applyBindings(asdasd);
```

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="rangeslider: test"></div>
```

Problem is that `valueAccessor()` inside `init` is empty, but alert stays that it has values. It works fine if I am passing `rangeslider: test()` (unwraping observable), but I need change value of that observable from `init`.

So where this value lost without notifying about it change?

http://jsfiddle.net/86sAP/3/ - live example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to unwrap valueAccessor to get observable's value:

```
length = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()).length;
```

Here is updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/86sAP/4/

Comment: WAT... Why? oO unwrapObservable it just ko.isObservable(value) ? value() : value. That's only to ensure that you working your object rather that function. But why that works?

Comment: Can't understand why ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) just works but neither valueAccessor nor valueAccessor() doesn't? oO

Comment: You passing observable to the binding so to get its value you should unwrap it, valueAccessor() is just returning that observable.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot valueAccessor()() returns correct value. But still can't understand that valueAccessor() is [] rather than function observable() { //blahblah } (which returns for example console.log( ko.observable(0) ) )

Comment: Ahh, because that is observableArray but not simply observable. That was very confusing typeof valueAccessor() = function. But I thought []  is just empty array